# What is as_index in groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What exactly is the function of `as_index` in `groupby` in Pandas?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`print()` is your friend when you don't understand a thing. It clears out doubts many times.

Take a look:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'books':['bk1','bk1','bk1','bk2','bk2','bk3'], 'price': [12,12,12,15,15,17]})

print(df)

print(df.groupby('books', as_index=True).sum())

print(df.groupby('books', as_index=False).sum())
```

Output:

```
  books  price
0   bk1     12
1   bk1     12
2   bk1     12
3   bk2     15
4   bk2     15
5   bk3     17

       price
books       
bk1       36
bk2       30
bk3       17

  books  price
0   bk1     36
1   bk2     30
2   bk3     17
```

When `as_index=True` the key(s) you use in `groupby()` will become an index in the new dataframe.

The benefits you get when you set the column as index are:

1. **Speed.** When you filter values based on the index column eg. `df.loc['bk1']`, it would be faster because of hashing of index column. It doesn't have to traverse the entire `books` column to find `'bk1'`. It will just calculate the hash value of `'bk1'` and find it in 1 go.
2. **Ease.** When `as_index=True` you can use this syntax `df.loc['bk1']` which is shorter and faster as opposed to `df.loc[df.books=='bk1']` which is longer and slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dint know about print.

Comment: @Haritha It is a general rule in programming. `print` out everything that is creating doubt. In early days of programming `print` statements were inserted everywhere in the program to debug errros. If you think I have answered your question, then consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark '✔' on the left of answer below the two triangles.

Comment: In addition to easy selection, `df.loc['bk1']` is also faster than boolean indexing.

Comment: @ayhan Yep. It doesn't have to traverse the entire books column to find `'bk1'` when it's indexed. It will just calculate the hash value of 'bk1' and find it in 1 go. Thanks for raising that point.

Answer (score 7):

When using the group by function, as_index can be set to true or false depending on if you want the column by which you grouped to be the index of the output.

```
import pandas as pd
table_r = pd.DataFrame({
    'colors': ['orange', 'red', 'orange', 'red'],
    'price': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
    'quantity': [500, 3000, 3000, 4000],
})
new_group = table_r.groupby('colors',as_index=True).count().sort('price', ascending=False)
print(new_group)
```

output:

```
        price  quantity
colors                 
orange      2         2
red         2         2
```

Now with as_index=False

```
   colors  price  quantity
0  orange      2         2
1     red      2         2
```

Note how colors is no longer an index when we change as_index=False

Answer (score 0):

One limitation of setting `as_index = True` is that it means you can't use that column in a `df.pivot()` method. You have to reset it to `False` before calling the pivot:

```
df_test = df[['drive-wheels', 'body-style', 'price']]      
df_group = df_test.groupby(['drive-wheels', 'body-style'], as_index=False).mean() # must be False for the pivot to work
df_pivot = df_group.pivot(index='drive-wheels', columns='body-style')
```