# How to slice a pandas MultiIndex df keeping all values until a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a 3-level MultiIndex dataframe and I would like to slice it such that  all the values until a certain condition is met are kept. To make an example, I have the following dataframe:

```
                           Col1  Col2
Date          Range  Label
'2018-08-01'  1      A     900   815
                     B     850   820
                     C     800   820
                     D     950   840
              2      A     900   820
                     B     750   850
                     C     850   820
                     D     850   800
```

And I would like to select all the values until Col1 becomes smaller than Col2. As soon as I have an instance for which Col1 < Col2 then I don't care about the data anymore and I would like to remove them (even if Col1 becomes larger than Col2 again). 
Considering the example above this is the dataframe that I would like to obtain:

```
                           Col1  Col2
Date          Range  Label
'2018-08-01'  1      A     900   815
                     B     850   820
              2      A     900   820
```

I tried several options but I haven't find a good solution yet. I can easily keep all the data for which Col1 > Col2 with:

```
df_new=df[df['Col1']>df['Col2']]
```

but this is not what I need. I've also been thinking about cycling through the level 1 index and slice the dataframe with pd.IndexSlice:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
idx_lev1=df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()

for j in (idx_lev1):
    df_lev1=df.loc[idx[:,j,:],:]
    idxs=df_lev1.index.get_level_values(2)[np.where(df_lev1['Col1']<df_lev1['Col2'])[0][0]-1]
    df_sliced= df_lev1.loc[idx[:,:,:idxs],:]
```

and then concatenate the various dataframes afterwards. 
However, this is not efficient (my dataframe has more than 3 millions entries so this is also something I have to consider) and I have the problem that the range index is repeated for different dates, so I would probably have to nest 2 cycles or something similar.

I'm sure there must be a simple and more pythonic solution but I wasn't able to find a way around this.

In case you want to generate the dataframe above for testing you could use:

```
from io import StringIO
s="""                         
Date  Range  Label  Col1  Col2
'2018-08-01'  1  A  900   815
'2018-08-01'  1  B  850   820
'2018-08-01'  1  C  800   820
'2018-08-01'  1  D  950   840
'2018-08-01'  2  A  900   820
'2018-08-01'  2  B  750   850
'2018-08-01'  2  C  850   820
'2018-08-01'  2  D  850   800
"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),
             sep='\s+',
             index_col=['Date','Range','Label'])
```

### **Update:**

I tried to implement both the solution from [Adam.Er8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5052365/adam-er8) and from [Alexandre B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10041823/alexandre-b) they work fine with the test dataframe I created for SO but not with the real data.
The problem is that there may be instances for which Col1 values are always larger than Col2 and in this case I would just like to keep all the data. None of the solutions proposed so far can really deal with this problem.

For a more realistic test case you can use this example:

```
s="""                         
Date  Range  Label  Col1  Col2
'2018-08-01'  1  1  900   815
'2018-08-01'  1  2  950   820
'2018-08-01'  1  3  900   820
'2018-08-01'  1  4  950   840
'2018-08-01'  2  1  900   820
'2018-08-01'  2  2  750   850
'2018-08-01'  2  3  850   820
'2018-08-01'  2  4  850   800
'2018-08-02'  1  1  900   815
'2018-08-02'  1  2  850   820
'2018-08-02'  1  3  800   820
'2018-08-02'  1  4  950   840
'2018-08-02'  2  1  900   820
'2018-08-02'  2  2  750   850
'2018-08-02'  2  3  850   820
'2018-08-02'  2  4  850   800
"""
```

Alternatively, you can download a hdf file from [here](https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/ZkO9Amg3nMeOL5z). This is a subset of the dataframe I'm really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use [`.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to number each row, then find the first row that has the right condition, and use it to filter only rows that have a number lower than that.

try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s="""
Date  Range  Label  Col1  Col2
'2018-08-01'  1  1  900   815
'2018-08-01'  1  2  950   820
'2018-08-01'  1  3  900   820
'2018-08-01'  1  4  950   840
'2018-08-01'  2  1  900   820
'2018-08-01'  2  2  750   850
'2018-08-01'  2  3  850   820
'2018-08-01'  2  4  850   800
'2018-08-02'  1  1  900   815
'2018-08-02'  1  2  850   820
'2018-08-02'  1  3  800   820
'2018-08-02'  1  4  950   840
'2018-08-02'  2  1  900   820
'2018-08-02'  2  2  750   850
'2018-08-02'  2  3  850   820
'2018-08-02'  2  4  850   800
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),
                 sep='\s+',
                 index_col=['Date', 'Range', 'Label'])

groupby_date_range = df.groupby(["Date", "Range"])
df["cumcount"] = groupby_date_range.cumcount()

first_col1_lt_col2 = defaultdict(lambda: len(df), df[df['Col1'] < df['Col2']].groupby(["Date", "Range"])["cumcount"].min().to_dict())

result = df[df.apply(lambda row: row["cumcount"] < first_col1_lt_col2[row.name[:2]], axis=1)].drop(columns="cumcount")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
                          Col1  Col2
Date         Range Label            
'2018-08-01' 1     1       900   815
                   2       950   820
                   3       900   820
                   4       950   840
             2     1       900   820
'2018-08-02' 1     1       900   815
                   2       850   820
             2     1       900   820
```

Comment: BTW if someone has any idea how to use the result of `.min()` directly, avoiding `to_dict` and `apply` later, that'd be great if you suggest an improvement :)

Comment: Arn't those columns indices?

Comment: I updated my question, the problem with your solution is that it cannot handle cases where Col1 values are always larger than Col2 (my fault that I didn't specify this in the first place). If you can find a workaround I would be happy to accept your solution.

Comment: @baccandr OK, perfect, I edited my answer, now my dict is a defaultdict that defaults to len(df), so if now Col1<Col2 is found, it will take all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `np.where` and select the first indice.

The `as_index=False` in the groupby give you the opportunity to ignore the index column in the `groupby`. Have a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236370/what-is-as-index-in-groupby-in-pandas)

Code:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index() \
         .groupby(by=["Range", "Date"], as_index=False) \
         .apply(lambda x: x.head(np.where(x.Col1 < x.Col2)[0][0])) \
         .set_index(["Date", "Range", "Label"])

print(df2)
#                           Col1  Col2
# Date         Range Label
# '2018-08-01' 1     A       900   815
#                    B       850   820
#              2     A       900   820
```

Answer (score 0):

First we make a *"helper"* column to cumcount each group. Then we filter all the rows in our groupby where `Col1 < Col2` and get the cumcount above that:

```
df2['cumcount'] = df2.groupby(level=1).cumcount()

dfs = []

for idx, d in df2.groupby(level=1):
    n = d.loc[(d['Col1'] < d['Col2']), 'cumcount'].min()-1
    dfs.append(d.loc[d['cumcount'].le(n)])

df_final = pd.concat(dfs).drop('cumcount', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                          Col1  Col2
Date         Range Label            
'2018-08-01' 1     A       900   815
                   B       850   820
             2     A       900   820
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```
# create a dataframe with a similar structure as yours
data={
'Date': ['2019-04-08', '2019-06-27', '2019-04-05', '2019-05-01', '2019-04-09', '2019-06-19', '2019-04-25', '2019-05-18', '2019-06-10', '2019-05-19', '2019-07-01', '2019-04-07', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-01', '2019-06-09', '2019-04-17', '2019-04-27', '2019-05-27', '2019-06-29', '2019-04-24'],
'Key1': ['B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
'Col1': [670, 860, 658, 685, 628, 826, 871, 510, 707, 775, 707, 576, 800, 556, 833, 551, 591, 492, 647, 414],
'Col2': [442, 451, 383, 201, 424, 342, 315, 548, 321, 279, 379, 246, 269, 461, 461, 371, 342, 327, 226, 467],
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(['Date', 'Key1'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
df.set_index(['Date', 'Key1'], inplace=True)

# here the real work starts
# temporarily create a dataframe with the comparison
# which has a simple numeric index to be used later
# to slice the original dataframe
df2= (df['Col1']<df['Col2']).reset_index()

# we only want to see the rows from the first row
# to the last row before a row in which Col1<Col2
all_unwanted= (df2.loc[df2[0] == True, [0]])
if len(all_unwanted) > 0:
    # good there was such a row, so we can use it's index
    # to slice our dataframe
    show_up_to= all_unwanted.idxmin()[0]
else:
    # no, there was no such row, so just display everything
    show_up_to= len(df)
# use the row number to slice our dataframe
df.iloc[0:show_up_to]
```

The output is:

```
                 Col1  Col2
Date       Key1            
2019-03-31 C      800   269
2019-04-01 A      556   461
2019-04-05 C      658   383
2019-04-07 A      576   246
2019-04-08 B      670   442
2019-04-09 C      628   424
2019-04-17 B      551   371
--------------------------- <-- cutting off the following lines:
2019-04-24 A      414   467
2019-04-25 A      871   315
2019-04-27 B      591   342
2019-05-01 A      685   201
2019-05-18 C      510   548
2019-05-19 C      775   279
2019-05-27 B      492   327
2019-06-09 A      833   461
2019-06-10 A      707   321
2019-06-19 B      826   342
2019-06-27 B      860   451
2019-06-29 A      647   226
2019-07-01 A      707   379
```